# Regular Expression to capture two different datetime formats

Tags: regex, python-3.x, datetime

I have file in which there are dates with two different formats:

- 2019-12-15-11-52
- 20191215.0900

I want to write a regular expression in Python to catch both of them.
I came up with the following regular expression.

`\d{4}\-?\d{2}\-?\d{2}[\.|\-]\d{2}\-?\d{2}`

I tested the above regex on the site below and it appears to work fine:
https://regex101.com/

I'm wondering if there's a simpler regex to do the same thing and if the actual regex string affects the performance of Python's regex matching.

Comment: Your regex is simple. Note that it may also match strings like `2019-12-15.11-52`, `2019-1215.0900`, etc. and it is not clear what your requirements are.

Comment: It might be better to match each format specifically as an alternation `\d{4}(-\d{2}){4}|\d{8}\.\d{4}` https://regex101.com/r/LSNsa1/1

Comment: `\d{8}\.\d{4}|\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){4}` with non capturing [101](https://regex101.com/r/i4ufSR/1)

Comment: does `\d{4}.*[-\d{2}]{4}` suit your needs?

Comment: Or perhaps a more exact match using a backreference for the delimiters and as the next step parse the match as a date `\b\d{4}(-?)\d{2}\1\d{2}(?:\.\d{4}|\1\d{2}\1\d{2})\b` https://regex101.com/r/KHfNiy/1

Comment: Thanks the replies are really great, I didn't really think the problem of capturing date formats that aren't in the file, e.g. `2019-12-15.11-52` and the possible alternative regexes!

Comment: @BSQL: your regex matches `1234lkjhfsdf*!:;{}{}`